# Two Colliders on the same GameObject for different purposes

Tags: unity, collision-detection, component-based, collider, monobehaviour

I'm somewhat new to Unity and am trying to build a battle system.
Right now, I have an attack that checks collisions with enemy objects like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
  if (other.gameObject.layer != LayerMask.NameToLayer(_hurtboxLayer))
    return;

  var enemyHealth = other.GetComponent<Health>();
  enemyHealth.TakeDamage(_damagePoints);
}
```

My game also uses Rigidbody2D objects to let the player and enemies bump into each other.
Because I want the "bumping" Collider2D be different from the hitbox Collider2D, I made a child GameObject called Hurtbox for each enemy.
The Hurtbox objects have a Health behaviour which handles the HP and death of an enemy:

```
public class Health : MonoBehaviour {

  [SerializeField] private int _initialHealthPoints;
  private int _healthPoints;

  public void TakeDamage(int damagePoints) {
    _healthPoints -= damagePoints;

    if (_healthPoints <= 0) {
      Die();
    }
  }

  private void Die() {
    Destroy(gameObject);
  }

  private void Start() {
    _healthPoints = _initialHealthPoints;
  }

}
```

The `Die` method only destroys the hurtbox object and is not allowed to destroy the enemy object, which is its parent.
Is there any way I can put both Collider2Ds and the Health behaviour on the same GameObject and only check a specific Collider in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method?

Comment: It sounds like you have a perfectly workable solution with multiple game objects right now. Why do you want to reduce to one game object instead?

Comment: @DMGregory When I called the `Die` method before, I would only destroy the Hurtbox object, not the parent object that holds the Rigidbody, SpriteRenderer, etc. But I just checked now, the code works fine, if I attach the Health behaviour to the Hurtbox object and then call `Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject)` from `Die`.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As DMGregory pointed out, my solution was on the right track. What I do differently now, is that now the Health behaviour detroys its parent. I had an exception when I tried this the first time, but that might have been because I put the code in the wrong behaviour. Also, I made sure to check the Physics 2D settings to make sure, the Hurtbox objects wouldn't collide with any other objects.

My game objects:

- Character/Enemy (Rigidbody2D, Box Collider 2D)

  - Hurtbox (Box Collider 2D, Health)
- Projectile (Box Collider 2D, Projectile behaviour) -> instantiated by character/enemy

**Projectile Code**

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
  if (other.gameObject.layer != _hurtboxLayerMask)
    return;

  var enemyHealth = other.GetComponent<Health>();
  enemyHealth.TakeDamage(damagePoints);
  Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

**Health behaviour**

```
public class Health : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private int initialHealthPoints;
  private int _healthPoints;
  
  public void TakeDamage(int damagePoints) {
    HealthPoints -= damagePoints;
    
    if (HealthPoints <= 0) {
      Die();
    }
  }

  private void Die() {
    Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
  }

  private void Start() {
    HealthPoints = TotalHealthPoints = initialHealthPoints;
  }

  public int TotalHealthPoints { get; private set; }
  public int HealthPoints { get; private set; }
}
```